# Encrypting the input and output of a docker container

Tags: docker, encryption, containers

I have a docker container and someone is going to run this container and it will provide some form of communication (e.g. a simple REST service).

I don't want the user who runs the docker to have access to the data that is sent to the docker or the data that is being received. Is this feasible?

The easiest solution that comes to my mind is that I can encrypt the data before sending it to the docker. But is there a way to prevent the user to have access to the key required for decrypting this data which is stored inside the docker container?

Comment: You can make it hard to do, but you can't prevent the owner of the docker host from seeing the data if they want to.

Comment: More specifically, anyone who can run any `docker` command can use it to read any write any file on the host or in any container.  So you can encrypt the HTTP traffic, but a system administrator (that is, anyone who can `docker run` anything) can also get the encryption keys back out of the container.